# Java LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

Can someone help me on how can I use the first score if the score is equals to 3 the player gets to get another attempt to shot.

Here is what I've tried.

```
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
        int max = 3;
        int min = 0;
        int range = max - min + 1;
        
        int score = 0;
        
        list.add("Player 1: ");
        list.add("Player 2: ");
        list.add("Player 3: ");
        list.add("Player 4: ");
        list.add("Player 5: ");
        
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            int att = (int)(Math.random() * range) + min;
            if (att == 3) {
                System.out.println(list.get(i) + att);
                score = att;
                score++;
                
                if (score == 3) {
                    int nextscore = score + att;
                    System.out.println(list.get(i) + nextscore);
                }
            }
            
            if (att <= 2) {
                System.out.println(list.get(i) + att);
            }
            
        }
```

if the random attempt shot is equals to 3 then the same players gets another shot, therefore if the player shots another and gets another random score then the first random attempt shot/score will be added to the second attempt random. But the problem is I don't know how can I add it.

Here is my output.

```
Player 1: 3 //The random attempt shot is 3 but the score didn't added for the second attempt.
Player 2: 2
Player 3: 1
Player 4: 1
Player 5: 2
```

Note that each perfect score or 3 points would let the same player shot again. and I don't get what I want please help.

Comment: You check if att equals 3 and set score to att. Then add one to score so that will be 4. Therefore if (score == 3) will never be true. Also, I feel a map would be more suitable for this than a list.

Comment: I haven't use map yet, I don't know how map works and how to do it. We're still on Linked List , so I don't get what mapping is.